# How to sort a DataGrid by a column that's been bound to an interface property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a DataGrid in a View bound to a collection a ViewModel, and some of the columns in that DataGrid are bound to an interface property because the object uses the interface's default implementation for those properties.

Here's a simplification of the interface and class:

```cs
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IExampleInterface
    {
        public object ExampleProperty1 { get; }
        public object ExampleProperty2 { get; }
        public object ExampleProperty3
        {
            // Returns value calculated using ExampleProperty1 & ExampleProperty2.
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Models
{
    public class ExampleObject : Interfaces.IExampleInterface
    {
        public object ExampleProperty1 { get; set; }
        public object ExampleProperty2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The collection definition is:

```cs
public List<ExampleObject> Objects
{
    get
    {
        return _objects;
    }
    set
    {
        _objects = value;
        // Raises the PropertyChanged event for the property.
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the xaml:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!--Other Columns-->
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=(interfaceNamespace:IExampleInterface.ExampleProperty3)}" />
        <!--Other Columns-->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that whenever the user selects the header of one of these interface property bound columns to sort the DataGrid by, the DataGrid is not sorted and the Output window of Visual Studio displays this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(0)' property not found on 'object' ''ExampleObject' (HashCode=6249895)'. null

Is there a way to allow the user to sort the DataGrid by a column whose content is bound to an interface property?

I've tried changing the type of the collection to an `ObservableCollection`, thinking maybe the problem was that the view was not being notified after the property was sorted, but no dice.


I've also just implemented the properties in the class with a copy of the interface's default implementation.
Which *does* work, but defeats the purpose of having a default implementation for the interface, which is why I'm hoping there's another, better way for this to be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the `SortMemberPath` property of the column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="(interfaceNamespace:IExampleInterface.ExampleProperty)" ... />
```

Comment: The error in the output window was changed to:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(interfaceNamespace:IExampleInterface.ExampleProperty)' property not found on 'object' ''ExampleObject' (HashCode=6249895)'. null

I tried setting `DataGrid.ItemTemplate` to `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type interfaceNamespace:IExampleInterface}" />` so that it would treat the item as its interface, but no luck.

Creating a new collection property of `IExampleInterface` for the DataGrid to bind to didn't work either.

Comment: The sorting works for me. How is your `ExampleObject` defined? Please update your question with all details necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I just tried it again on another property and it worked, so I took a look at the difference between that and the my first test and turns out there was a misspelling in my first attempt. My apologies for not noticing before my comment.

There seems to be an issue using the path of a property that isn't the one bound to the column, but I guess that's out of scope of the original question at this point.

Thank you for your help.